# Triples of Arrangements, An Introduction to Hyperplane Arrangements

Tags: combinatorial-geometry

I'm making my way through Richard P. Stanley's [*An Introduction to Hyperplane Arrangements*](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ecis6100/sp06stanley.pdf), and am having a bit of difficulty processing the definition of triple's of arrangements. The document states, on page 13 that:

> 2.1. Properties of the intersection poset.
>
> Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an arrangement in the vector space V. A subarrangement of $\mathcal{A}$ is a subset $\mathcal{B}$ ⊆ $\mathcal{A}$. Thus $\mathcal{B}$
> is also an arrangement in V. If $x$ ∈ L($\mathcal{A}$), define the subarrangement
> $\mathcal{A}_x$ ⊆ $\mathcal{A}$ by
>
> $\mathcal{A}_x$ = {$H \in \mathcal{A} : x \subseteq H$}.
>
> Also define an arrangement $\mathcal{A}^x$ in the affine subspace x ∈ L($\mathcal{A}$) by
>
> $\mathcal{A}^x$ ={$x$∩H$\neq$∅ : $H \in \mathcal{A} - \mathcal{A}_x$}.

Where $L(\mathcal{A})$ is the poset of $\mathcal{A}$. Now let me first say that I believe the definition of $\mathcal{A}^x$ to be slightly incorrect, as it should be an *arrangement*, and should instead read:

$\mathcal{A}^x = \{H \in \mathcal{A} - \mathcal{A}_x: x \cap H\neq \emptyset\}$.

That is, all hyperplanes that intersect $x$ but are not supersets of $x$. A little bit further down on page 13 it states:

> Choose $H_0 \in \mathcal{A}$. Let $\mathcal{A}′$ = $\mathcal{A}−\{H_0\}$ and $\mathcal{A}′′$ = $A^{H_0}$. We call $(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{A}′,\mathcal{A}′′)$ a
> triple of arrangements with distinguished hyperplane $H_0$.

An example figure is provided on the following page:

[image]

I can easily see how $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{A}'$ match the definitions provided. However, my understanding of $\mathcal{A}''$ is:

$\mathcal{A}'' = \mathcal{A}^{H_0} = \{H \in \mathcal{A} - \mathcal{A}_{H_0}: H_0 \cap H\neq \emptyset\}$.

where

$\mathcal{A}_{H_0} = \{ H_0 \}$.

With respect to the diagram, and if my understanding is correct, I make 3 points:

1. $H_0$ should not be part of the diagram, but obviously is.
2. There are 3 hyperplanes that should be part of the solution, but aren't.
3. There seems to be emphasis on points of intersection that is not part of the definition.

Going by the figure, it strikes me that maybe the definition of $\mathcal{A}^x$ is meant to be:

$\mathcal{A}^x = \{y: y \in L(\mathcal{A}), y \subseteq x\}$

But obviously this is nothing like the given definition. Could someone clarify the explanation please?

I have also checked the errata document [that can be found here](https://math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/arrangements/errata.pdf), but that does not provide any additional clarity.